# Wordpress, search in excerpt instead content

Tags: php, full-text-search, wordpress

im new posting in the forum, but here i found answers without ask, just searching, thanks about that.

Here go my questions:

I have a custom post type called 'publicacion' and there the next custom WP_Query:

```
$query_args = array( 
        's' => mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['s'] ),
        'post_type' => 'publicacion',
        'meta_key' => 'meta-box-fp'
    );

    if( $_GET['autor'] != '' ) {
        $query_args['tax_query'] = array( 
                                        array( 
                                            'taxonomy' => 'autores', 
                                            'field' => 'slug', 
                                            'terms' => mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['autor'] ) 
                                        ) 
                                    );
    }

    if( trim( $_GET['fini'] ) != '' || trim( $_GET['ffin'] ) != '' ) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = array ( 
                                        array( 
                                            'key' => 'meta-box-fp',
                                            'value' => array( mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['fini'] ) . '-00-00', mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['ffin'] ) . '-00-00' ), 
                                            'type' => 'DATE',
                                            'compare' => 'BETWEEN' ) 
                                    );
    }

    if( isset( $_GET['ord_by'] ) ) {
        $ordby = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['ord_by'] ) == 'year' ? 'meta_value' : mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['ord_by'] );
        $query_args['orderby'] = $ordby;//mysql_escape_string( $_GET['ord_by'] );
        $query_args['order'] = 'DESC';//mysql_escape_string( $_GET['ord'] );
    }

    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

The 's' parameter redirects to the search page, but i need do the search in the archive-publicacion.php file, and i need the 's' parameter, search for excerpt instead content. 
It is possible to do that? Thanks and i hope be clear in my question and excuse me my english.

Answer (score 0):

well.. i've resolved my issue by adding the query parameters in functions.php from theme instead from archive.php and changing the 's' to 'str' from the url for not redirect the query when wordpress reads the url. 
This looks something like this functions.php:

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_search' );
function my_custom_search( $query ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get('post_type') == 'publicacion' ) {

        if( isset( $_GET['str'] ) && !empty( $_GET['str'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 's', mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['str'] ) );
        }

        if( ( isset( $_GET['fini'] ) && !empty( $_GET['fini'] ) ) && ( isset( $_GET['ffin'] ) && !empty( $_GET['ffin'] ) ) ) {
            $fini = !empty( $_GET['fini'] ) ? mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['fini'] ) . '-00-00' : '1900-00-00';
            $ffin = !empty( $_GET['ffin'] ) ? mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['ffin'] ) . '-00-00' : date( 'Y' ) . '-00-00';
            $args_meta_query = array(
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'meta-box-fp', 
                                            'value' => array( $fini, $ffin ), 
                                            'type' => 'DATE', 
                                            'compare' => 'BETWEEN' 
                                        )
                                );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $args_meta_query );
        }

        if( isset( $_GET['autor'] ) && !empty( $_GET['autor'] ) ) {
            $args_tax_query = array(
                                        array( 
                                            'taxonomy' => 'autores', 
                                            'field' => 'slug', 
                                            'terms' => mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['autor'] ) 
                                        )
                                );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', $args_tax_query ); 
        }

        if( isset( $_GET['ordby'] ) && $_GET['ordby'] != 'fecha' ) {
            $ordby = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['ordby'] );
            $query->set( 'orderby', $ordby );
            $query->set( 'order', strtoupper( mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['ord'] ) ) );
        }else {
            $ord = isset( $_GET['ord'] ) && !empty( $_GET['ord'] ) ? strtoupper( mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['ord'] ) ) : 'DESC';
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'meta-box-fp' );
            $query->set( 'order', $ord );
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this help somebody and excuse me my english again. 
Bye.